# Error: I keep getting "A promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it"

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, promise, bluebird, es6-promise

I'm having trouble figuring out why I can suppress this warning

Method causing the error

```
    CreateSettingsList.    init: function () {
  var collection = new $pnp.Web(config.settings.defaultCollection);

  return collection.lists.ensure(SPConfig.listName, SPConfig.listDescription, 100, false, {
      EnableVersioning: true,
      Hidden: true
    })
    .then(r => {
      // console.log("List created:", r.created);

      // IF SETTINGS LIST EXIST RETURN SETTINGS 
      if (!r.created) {
        //console.log('Config list exists');

        return collection.lists
          .getByTitle(SPConfig.listName).items
          .getById(1).select("Settings")
          .usingCaching().get()
          .then(item => {
            config = JSON.parse(item.Settings);
            SETTINGS_LOADED = true;
            return config;
          })
          .catch(console.log);

      } else {
        // CREATE CONFIG LIST - RETURN SETTINGS
        console.log('Creating list');

        // Variable setup 
        var batch = $pnp.sp.createBatch();
        var list = collection.lists.getByTitle(SPConfig.listName);

        // Add settings field 
        list.fields.inBatch(batch).addMultilineText(SPConfig.listField, 10, false, false, false, false, undefined)
          .then(_ => console.log("created field"))
          .catch(console.log);

        // Update View 
        list.views.getByTitle(SPConfig.listView)
          .fields.inBatch(batch).add(SPConfig.listField)
          .then(_ => console.log("update view"))
          .catch(console.log);

        // Add default settings
        list.items.inBatch(batch).add({
            Title: SPConfig.listTitle,
            Settings: JSON.stringify(config)
          })
          .then(_ => console.log("created item"))
          .catch(console.log);

        // Execute batch  
        return batch.execute()
          .then(_ => {
            SETTINGS_LOADED = true;
            return config;
          })
          .catch(e => {
            throw e;
          });
      }
    })
    .catch(console.log);
}
```

When it's called (SettingService):

```
  function loadSettings() {    
      // CHECK IF SETTINGS LIST EXISTS BEFORE GETTING ITEM
      return CreateSettingsList.init();
    }
  }
```

When that's called:

```
function getAccess() {
    if (!ACCESS_CHECKED) {
      SettingService.loadSettings().then(function (config) { settings = config; });
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make sure I'm returning something where ever I've made a promise call and I was getting more of these before but I thought I figured out how to solve them but this one won't go away.

Comment: Um, instead of `.then( s => sth().then( s => sth.then(...) ) )` , you can do `.then( s => sth() ).then( s => sth() ).then( s => sth() )` which makes the thing much more readable.

Comment: That's a good point, but I ended up refactoring (updated OP) to use a batch operation for those functions. I still get the warning though.

Comment: the code `SettingService.loadSettings().then(.....);` in your fuction `getAccess` is creating a promise that is never returned ... you're also creating a defered `var d = $q.defer()` for absolutely no reason

Answer (score 0):

In the `else` clause, the three sections "Add settings field", "Update View" and "Add default settings" each creates a promise, none of which contributes to the promise returned by `CreateSettingsList.init()`, hence the warning.

It's hard to say exactly what fix should be applied but one option would be to aggregate those three promises and only perform `batch.execute()` if all three fulfill.

```
CreateSettingsList.init: function() {
    var collection = new $pnp.Web(config.settings.defaultCollection);
    return collection.lists.ensure(SPConfig.listName, SPConfig.listDescription, 100, false, {
        EnableVersioning: true,
        Hidden: true
    })
    .then(r => {
        // IF SETTINGS LIST EXIST RETURN SETTINGS 
        if (!r.created) {
            return collection.lists
            .getByTitle(SPConfig.listName).items
            .getById(1).select("Settings")
            .usingCaching().get()
            .then(item => {
                config = JSON.parse(item.Settings);
                SETTINGS_LOADED = true;
                return config;
            })
            .catch(console.log);
        } else {
            // CREATE CONFIG LIST - RETURN SETTINGS
            console.log('Creating list');

            // Variable setup 
            var batch = $pnp.sp.createBatch();
            var list = collection.lists.getByTitle(SPConfig.listName);

            // Add settings field 
            var p1 = list.fields.inBatch(batch).addMultilineText(SPConfig.listField, 10, false, false, false, false, undefined)
            .then(() => console.log('created field'))
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                throw err; // optional: rethrow error to suppress downstream success handling
            });

            // Update View
            var p2 = list.views.getByTitle(SPConfig.listView)
            .fields.inBatch(batch).add(SPConfig.listField)
            .then(() => console.log('update view'))
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                throw err; // optional: rethrow error to suppress downstream success handling
            });

            // Add default settings
            var p3 = list.items.inBatch(batch).add({
                'Title': SPConfig.listTitle,
                'Settings': JSON.stringify(config)
            })
            .then(() => console.log('created item'))
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                throw err; // optional: rethrow error to suppress downstream success handling
            });

            // Execute batch
            return Promise.all([p1, p2, p3])
            .then(() => batch.execute())
            .then(() => {
                SETTINGS_LOADED = true;
                return config;
            });
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Other viable options would be :

- to perform `var p4 = batch.execute().then(...)` unconditionally and to `return Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4])`.
- to perform the four stages sequentially by chaining them together with `.then()`.

You will be more alive to what is appropriate than I am.